# How can I grab an ID from a dropdown list with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm doing a project on ASP.Net with the MVC methodology. I'm not using Entity Framework, I'm using a DAL that connects to a stored procedure. Like this:
[image]

I have a stored procedure for every action that I need (list, delete, edit,...). These are my tables on my database

[image]

Empleado means Employee, Pais means Country, Ciudad means City, Viaje means Trip
I have a problem I need to display a dropdown list with the countries, but If I click on one of them in the City display it should display the cities that are part of that country on my database.
This is how it looks like right now on the view:
[image]
On the stored procedure the code to display the cities is like this

```
SELECT [id]
      ,[id_pais]
      ,[ciudad]
  FROM [dbo].[Ciudad]
  WHERE id_pais = @id_pais
```

How can I send the ID from the country to that sps with JQuery?

Comment: You should handle `change` event of `pais` dropdown on client side (using jquery) then send the value (.val()`) to a controller, get matching cities and send them back (in JSON format) to the browser. Finally populate city dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

If i am understand your problem correctly. Use ".change()" jquery method for employee. From this method get the employee id and send the employee Id using AJAX and get the country data in  return. After this by using append method bind country in dropdown. Same goes for the city. I hope this will help.